# When will an anchor element not inherit color attribute of parent element?

Tags: css, inheritance

Here is my code:

```css
.blue {
    color:#6E99E1;
    font-size:9px;
}
```

```html
<span class="blue">::<a href="/equipment_new.php">CLICK HERE</a>:: to view our New Equipment inventory. <br /><br /></span>
```

I've somehow triggered something that prevented the `<a>` tag from inheriting color of parent `<span>`.

Comment: did you by chance just add the href attribute?

Comment: Others have answered your question already, but just thought I'll add that the css class definitions should be based on how they are used (e.g sidelinks, pageheader, productlist) and not on what they do (e.g. blue, boldtext, redborder).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By default an anchor tag does not inherit attributes like color if an href attribute is present.

Check out the difference between these two on a page:

```html
<span style=color:green><a href="t">test</a></span>
<span style=color:green><a>test</a></span>
```

The following link is to the w3 c:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2

> User agents generally render links in
>   such a way as to make them obvious to
>   users (underlining, reverse video,
>   etc.). The exact rendering depends on
>   the user agent. Rendering may vary
>   according to whether the user has
>   already visited the link or not.

.....

> Usually, the contents of A are not
>   rendered in any special way when A
>   defines an anchor only.

Comment: Do you have any reference for the point that "By default an anchor tag does not inherit attributes like color if an href attribute is present. "?

Comment: try it; if an anchor tag doesn't have a href attribute, it doesn't act like an anchor tag.

Comment: Yes,but I hope some reference link will make it clear if that's standard and why it's so.

Comment: I just added links to the w3c and it's explanation as to how anchor tags are rendered when not linking to another reference.

Comment: In step further,is there any rule for judging whether a certain attribute will be inherited or not?

Comment: yes, although that gets a little tricky. I would refer to the W3c as to what is supposed to inherit to what.  It depends on what type of tags they are and what css elements.

Comment: The answer is not precisely correct. The `color` attribute is inherited (for all element) by nature of the specification. However the user agent style sheet specifies the color blue for anchor elements with `href` attribute and therefore overwrites the otherwise inherited value. If you deleted the user agent style sheet, the anchor with `href` attribute would inherit the parent element's color.

Answer (score 62):

Just an addendum to the other responses, if you *want* your `<a>` tags to inherit the colour from their parent you can use

```
a {color: inherit; }
```

```css
.blue {
  color: #6E99E1;
  font-size: 9px;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<span class="blue">::<a href="/equipment_new.php">CLICK HERE</a>:: to view our New Equipment inventory. <br /><br /></span>
```

Answer (score 10):

This is an answer to the question as well as a reply to [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag/1144969#1144969) and its comments.

Anchor tags *do* inherit color, linked or not. The only reason they don't in practice is because they already have their color set in the browser's default stylesheet. The same can be said for the underlining of the link (which, I presume, you didn't notice, because you actually *want* it or had already changed it yourself).

In Firefox, you can see this in Firebug if you toggle "Show User Agent CSS" (or you can have a look at [Firefox's internal stylesheets](http://www.oppenheim.com.au/2008/07/06/how-to-view-firefoxs-default-internal-css-stylesheet/) directly. You can see the browser's defaults in Webkit's Web Inspector and Opera's Dragonfly as well. I don't think you can in IE.

I don't know of any site which has an overview of all browser's defaults. CSS2's  "informative" [HTML4 stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) as well as the [YUI reset stylesheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) would be a good starting point, but neither of them mention any (link) colors (the HTML4 stylesheet does mention the underline).

To find out which properties are inherited in general, you can use the [CSS2 reference property index table](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html) (see the "Inherited?" column). SitePoint also mentions it in its [CSS reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css).

So if you want to make sure your link inherits its color from its parent instead of from the browser's default stylesheet, you would ideally do something like this:

```css
.blue a:link {
    color: inherit;
}
```

You could set it for the different pseudo-classes separately (so `:visited`, `:hover` and `:active` as well), or for the `a` tag altogether.

However, [IE6 and IE7 don't support the `inherit` keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)#Values_and_units), so if you want to support them too, you'd have to set the color explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

I think `a` doesn't inherit color by default. (certainly it has always worked that way on my sites). Why not change

```
.blue {
    color:#6E99E1;
    font-size:9px;
}
```

to

```
.blue, .blue a{
    color:#6E99E1;
    font-size:9px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) will show you exactly which style rules are applied to which elements.  It's perfect for this.

(A non-CSS possibility: Do you have `link/alink/vlink` attributes on your `<body>` tag?)

**Edit**: Duh, silly me, the others have it right - `<a href>` doesn't inherit colour.  But Firebug is still a good tool for this kind of problem (even if I'm not. 8-)

Comment: If <a> is somehow overriding your blue class, you can also just change your declaration to .blue, .blue a {...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to firebug (which should be your first port of call), the [**IE developer toolbar**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en) will also tell you where a given style is sourced from, just in case IE - shock, horror - should be different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the color of the links to override the default blue color.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing the a:visited colouring. Try this:

```
.blue, .blue:link, .blue:visited {
  color:#6E99E1;
  font-size:9px;
}
```