# Change text and link-color inside list-element on hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got an ordered list like this

```
<ol class="tracklist">
    <li>
        <a href="www.html">LINK</a>
        <span>some text</span>
     </li>
</ol>
```

I want to change the color of the list-numbers, link and span upon hovering on the list element.

Therefore I have this in css:

```
ol.tracklist li:hover {
    background-color: #D21600;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

It only changes the list-numbers and span's color though.

What can I do about this (without using JS).

Comment: I'm guessing `ol.strackslist` is just a typo in your question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anchor tags don't inherit attributes such as `color` when the `href` attribute is present.

You can use multiple selectors to apply the same style, separate them with a comma.

```
ol.tracklist li:hover, ol.tracklist li:hover a {
    background-color: #D21600;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Works marvellous. Could you explain why this selector applies to both?

Comment: `<a>` tags don't inherit attributes such as `color` when an `href` is present.  More info in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag).

Comment: The technical reason why anchors with `href` attributes don't inherit `color` from their parents is because browsers define a default color for `a:link` and friends, and these take precedence and their styles override the inherited styles.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have some extra **s's** in you styles

Change `ol.strackslist` to `ol.tracklist` in your css and it works.

You also need to add this for the link to change color:

```
ol.tracklist li:hover a, ol.tracklist li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/mje9t/1/

Comment: That only changes the link colour when the mouse is over the link, I'm guessing that's not what's required.

Comment: Good point @Town.  I've added `ol.tracklist li:hover a` to make that change.

Answer (score 2):

One can restore color inheritance on `<a>` also:

```css
ol.tracklist li a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

`<a>` behaves like any other element thereafter. Hovers on `<li>` will change its color as well.