# hyperlink css specificity inside a named element

Tags: css, css-specificity

http://jsfiddle.net/DkAqZ/9

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div>default black text</div>
    <div><a href="#">default red link</a></div>
    <div id="inner">
        <div>#inner green text</div>
        <div><a href="#">#inner red link or green text?</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    color:black;
}
a {
    color:red;
}
a:hover {
    color:orange;
}
#inner {
    color:green;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

**Looks like this**

[image: specificity]

I'm not entirely clear on why the second hyperlink is red and not green. isn't the specificity of `#inner` higher than `a`? also, the font-size IS inherited on the `#inner a` so that makes it even more confusing.

Comment: No, it's a UI feature (or bug, if you look at it that way) to visually and easily differentiate between interactive, though textual, elements (links) and plain text. Otherwise how would people be able to tell what was a link, if those links inherited the same colour as the surrounding text, just with the underline..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I'm pretty sure that's not the case. If you did:

```
#inner a { color:inherit}
```

I think that would work, don't have a chance to try it, sorry.

### Edit

This explains the situation far better: [when will "a" tag not inherit color attribute of parent tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag)

Hmmm... ok I just saw your nifty jsfiddle example. That's really nice. Removing the `href` doesn't seem to fix it, but my solution still works.

Comment: thanks that other SO link explained it. By default an anchor tag does not inherit attributes like color so as to differentiate between other text. makes sense

Comment: Yeah that was my initial instinct. Got thrown off by the comment that it had to do with the `href` definition, which isn't true.

Comment: The `href` attribute is concerned with the `:link` pseudo-class. `a` matches every such element regardless of that attribute, while `a:link` only matches unvisited `a[href]` links.