# Text colour changing in inspector but not on screen in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, selector

I am trying to make a short piece of script that changes the colour of a string of text when hovered over.

HTML:

```
<span class="headinglink" id="firstheading"><h1><a href="http://localhost/page.php">Link1</a></h1></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#firstheading').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('h1').stop().animate({ color: "#53799E" }, 1000);
    }, function() {
    $(this).find('h1').stop().animate({ color: "#F58426" }, 1000);
});
```

The weird thing is that when I open Chromes element inspector I can actually see the RGB value of the element above change is it should eg:

```
<h1 style="color: rgb(245, 132, 38); ">
```

But the elements actual colour does not change. Its like the external CSS is still over writing the inline CSS above.

Would anyone know how to get around this? Should I be ditching the external CSS for this element altogether?

(P.S I have both jQuery and UI libraries linked fine).

Comment: Works for me if you target the link instead of the heading http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NuJUB/

Comment: It is not a good idea to have `<h1>`, a block level element inside `<span>`, an inline element!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble here is that you're trying to change the color of the anchor, but you're actually changing the color of the heading. Simply replace `h1` with `a` and it should work.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47beB/) that demonstrates this.

**UPDATE**: In case you're wondering, this is because anchors don't inherit color by default. (ref: [when will "a" tag not inherit color attribute of parent tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag))