# Why won't my font colour change? CSS3

Tags: html, css

im trying to change the colour of #commentslink to white. All my other font styling (font- family, size) is working, just the colour won't change

My HTML is this;

```
<div id="commentslink">
  <div class="circle">
    <p><a href="">10</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS is this

```
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #0eb0d3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #0eb0d3;
  opacity: 0.4;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#commentslink {
  float: right;
  font-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.circle {
  float: right;
  background-color: #f89b2d;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Because there's only a link tag and `a:link` has a higher priority.

Comment: If you put `!important` after setting the color it will be applied over your general link styling.

Comment: @Nick wouldn't help the fact that it's `color`, and not `font-color`  though ;)

Answer (score 7):

First of all its only `color` and not `font-color: #ffffff;` and secondly you should use

```
#commentslink a { /* Specific selector */
    color: #fff;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VDErr/1/)

Let me tell you, the above selector will select all `a` tags inside the element having `#commentslink` as an `id` so if you want to target `a` nested inside `p` you can use a more specific selector like

```
#commentslink .circle p a { 
   /* Selects all a element nested inside p tag further nested inside an element 
      having class .circle which is further nested inside an element having 
      #commentslink as an id
   */
   color: #fff;
}
```

Just don't make your selectors overspecific if you don't really require, else you will end up making more and more nested rules thus bloating your CSS, so go as much basic as you can.

Last but not the least, this has nothing to do with CSS3

Just a good read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag).. related to this answer...

Comment: `@font-face` has something to do with CSS3 ^_^ ;)

Comment: @HashemQolami I just washed my face and read the question again, can't see `@font-face` anywhere :s :(

Comment: Absolutely, ِThe only thing is related to `font` and `CSS3`, is `@font-face` not `font-color`. didn't `^_^` help? :)

Comment: @HashemQolami nah, you getting it wrong buddy, this has nothing to do with CSS3 :)

Comment: We're on the same direction ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `!important`

```
 #commentslink {
    float: right;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
```

and use `color:` rather than `font-color`

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on [Mr. Alien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18241703/1542290), it's best to use the selector `#commentslink a`. CSS rules are applied in order of specificity, and the style for the `a` element is more specific than the styling for its parent element (`#commentslink`). The selector `#commentslink a` is more specific than either of the others, and will therefore take precedence.

Here's a good [article on specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

And as others have stated, the property is `color` not `font-color`.

[@Sobin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18241735/1542290), `!important` should be used sparingly, as it will clobber other rules applied to elements within the `#comments div`. Better to take advantage of specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `font-color` with **`color`**.

```
   #commentslink {
    float: right;
    color: #ffffff;   // this is enough not font-color
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
```

Also

```
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #0eb0d3;  // Also this a css override
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Update:** I just realized that above won't work.  I thought ***parent's css will override the child***.  But this is wrong here, since `a` tags have default color rendered by browsers.

```
#commentslink a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Thanks @Mr.  Alien for his fiddle and the SO link.

Comment: @Mr.Alien You're right.  Just now realized.  Thanks for pointing it.  But this have worked right?  The entire parent element font should be #fff.  Is this a broswer's default css setting for a tag?

Comment: You would like to read this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag

Answer (score 0):

The "10" is going to be #0eb0d3 because of the CSS styling applied to a tags.

Change

```
#commentslink {
float: right;
font-color: #ffffff;
font-size: 19px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
```

To
    #commentslink {
    float: right;
    font-color: #ffffff !important;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

And it will override the other styling