# One line of text refuses to change color

Tags: html, css, colors

I was doing a project recreating the google homepage in HTML/CSS and for the most part it came out fine except for some reason I can't get the text inside the "Sign Up" to change `color`.

```
<div id="contents">
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li id="signin"><a href="https://accounts...">Sign In</a></li>
```

I call it out in CSS with these lines.

```
#navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#signin {
    background-color: blue;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    }
```

I added `!important` thinking it would change but it didn't do a thing.
Also to note this is just some of the code there are other items on the nav bar that are all the same correct color.    I got the `background-color` to change but not the actual text `color`.

Comment: Simply because `<a>` elements do NOT inherit `color`. You need to specify the color of nested anchors - for instance - like so [`#signin a { color: inherit; }`](http://jsbin.com/tugega/1/edit).

Comment: The two styles specify different elements, they won't overwrite each other.

Comment: @HashemQolami Oh, can you pull up a W3/MDN link for that? thx

Comment: like this??   http://jsfiddle.net/ptzpr5fL/    if that's correct let me know so i can post it as the answer.

Comment: @DOCASAREL It has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag). To me, this question seems sort of duplicate. However I'll leave it open.

Comment: Ok this nailed it http://stackoverflow.com/a/1148776/2672018 ( **does** inherit but is stopped from user agent stylesheet )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other commenters were alluding to, you just need a separate CSS rule (`#signin a`) for the nested anchor tag.

```css
#navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#signin {
    background-color: blue;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 7px 12px;
}

#signin a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li id="signin"><a href="https://accounts...">Sign In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I get it now.  That worked perfectly.  I was going crazy trying to figure this out.  Thank you.