# Set font colors in CSS for links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, colors

I've been trying to get my navigation bar links to be one color while the main window has links in another color. I'm using a CSS stylesheet and it works but I think my main rule for `a` is overriding any other rules i have set as the `.leftside` navigation bar has the wrong color text. I even tried the `!IMPORTANT` but still nothing seems to fix it unless I remove the `a` rule in the CSS sheet.
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #303030;
}
.leftside {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 70px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #4C4C33;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftside">

  <a href="gallery.html">Image Gallery</a>

</div>
```

Comment: To change the link in the div use: `.leftside > a {}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [when will "a" tag not inherit color attribute of parent tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text inside `.leftside` **actually has** the color `white`. But *inside* `.leftside`, there is an `<a>`. You have defined separate style definitions for `<a>`, so the color from `.leftside` is **overridden**. Overriding is the main idea behind CSS (**Cascading**StyleSheet):

> The rule used is chosen by cascading down from the more general rules to the specific rule required. **The most specific rule is chosen.** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043046/4193263))

To fix the problem, you need to assign the color to the `<a>` *inside* `.leftside`, which can be done by using the more specific selector `.leftside a`:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #303030;
}
.leftside {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 70px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #4C4C33;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.leftside a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftside">

  <a href="gallery.html">Image Gallery</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been studying this and I think I understand it now :)

Answer (score 1):

from your css and html I don't see you setting a specific color for your links within the .leftside div. Here is an example of how I would set the css for the link (using the ***".leftside a"*** selector):

**html**

```
<div class="leftside">
    <!-- navigation link will be red -->
    <a href="gallery.html">Image Gallery</a>
</div>

<!-- non-navigation link will be default color -->
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Visit Google</a>
```

**css**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #303030;
}

.leftside {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 70px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #4C4C33;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
}

/* here is the selector for the link within the .leftside */
.leftside a {
    color: red;
}
```

**Additional notes**

You can also style links based on state. so to style your .leftside a links you would do the following (inspired by [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp))

```
/* unvisited link */
.leftside a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
.leftside a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
.leftside a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
.leftside a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```