# link item anchor CSS foreground color interactions between a { } and a:foo { }

Tags: html, css, colors, anchor

I have the following HTML code

```
    <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li ><a href="http://a.dummy.com/">A</a></li>
            <li class="selected"><a href="http://b.dummy.com/">B</a></li>
            <li ><a href="http://c.dummy.com/">C</a></li>
         </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

and the following CSS code

```
div nav ul li {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

div nav ul li.selected {
    color: black;
}
```

running on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz4zn77j/5/).

The white foreground color for text content entries "A", "B", and "C" is only showing up on the bullets. This is because as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag) illustrates, when an href attribute is present the color attribute is not inherited by the a tag.

However I don't understand how the color value for "div nav ul li a" interacts with
(the pseudoselectors)[http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp] "div nav ul li a:link", "div nav ul li a:visited", "div nav ul li a:hover", and "div nav ul li a:active".

Comment: what do you mean by "I don't understand why the color is not inherited by the a element."

Comment: See my updated post. I figured that part out but would like to know what the relationship between a and the four a:x pseudoclasses is.

Answer (score 2):

Because a tags have default color set by the browser (unlike p,span,div) so you have to set the color for the a tag.

```
div nav ul li {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
div nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
div nav ul li.selected {
    color: black;
}
div nav ul li.selected a{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: While your answer, so far as it goes, is correct you may wish to improve your answer by showing how to style the `<a>` elements - from the code in the question - with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

1. The color is not inherited by the a element becasuse you stopped at the **li** level. **div nav ul li**

This will only get the li element not the a element. If you want the a element

```
div nav ul li a{
    //CSS properties for the a element
}
```

2.The Psuedoselectors deal with an elements state and how it looks in that state. For instance if you wanted to change how your **a** element looks on hover you would do something like :

```
div nav ul li a:hover{
    color: orange;
    //CSS properties for the a element after hover
}
```

Comment: The 'pseudo-selectors' are '[pseudo-*classes*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes),' they're *real* selectors.

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/Lz4zn77j/6/)

Add

```
div nav ul li a {
    color: white;
}
```

to your CSS

In your CSS, you gave a style only for the `<li>`s and not for the `<a>`s inside the `<li>`s.

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/w7k7koxq/) to see the effects created by four of the pseudo-selectors.

- a:link - to specify style for the unvisited link
- a:visited - to specify style for the visited link
- a:hover - to specify style on mouse over
- a:active - to specify style on link selected

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to know what happens in the fiddle if the simple "div nav ul li a" is given a "color: #123456;" as well. Is this color overridden by the other four pseudoclasses and never used in this case?

Comment: It seems like in [this case](http://jsfiddle.net/w7k7koxq/1/) the "div nav ul li a { color: #123456; }" is never used. Is this observation correct?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this `div nav ul li { color: white; }` doesn't work is because that's for text inside the li, you need to target the link like this `div nav ul li a { color: white; }`

Take a look at the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz4zn77j/7/). Here you can see the effects of the link pseudo classes.

And here's a good [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) about them.  W3Schools isn't the best resource.