# css structural selector :first-child

Tags: css

If i apply following style on the given html below, why it is applying the style on everything inside the body element. I was assuming since the body is NOT the first child of html it should not apply this style onto anything inside body element.

:first-child { color: blue;}

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        :first-child { color: blue;}
    </style>
    <body>
      <div>
            <h1>This is a H6</h1>
            <p>Carz wtf noice pour uh saiz hoi.</p>
            <p>Oh winz lol wuv donutz yu. Herrow not wut carz pwety oh hornz. </p>
            <p>Bere noze dum cheezeburger oh. Notise hai mikrosoft foots. Dum oh iz nuthing gravy haz nozbody finking. Funnae hai nom winz noze r. </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>This is an H1</h1>
        <p>Sheeze dum can compewters flowerz. Loike choosday noice nom samez do hornz mac n. Funnae pour hoi dided gravy samez ghoast I.</p>
        <p> U pwety oh haz cat ghoast hai. Taytoes hornz hunnae hai meeeow ghoast. 
        </p>

        <h2>This is an h2</h2>
        <p>Sheeze meeeow dum uh dided cat nom hornz wuv. </p>
        <p>Donutz scratchin mac n dum rong ded gravy.</p>
        <p>Thx chz can hoi wtf. Evrybody yu u ded choosday evrybody hai neether. Iz hai dided sheeze bukket noice nozzing chz watzzup?. </p>
        <h2>this is another h2</h2>
        <p>Graet samez iz iz nozbody saiz sheeze oh carz. Jest kitteh not scratchin herrow. Nom scratchin rong saiz ya kitteh haz chz nom. </p>
        <p>Graet gravy gravy mikrosoft. Dided winz cheezeburger finking samez wtf foots. Gravy wut mac n partay noice noze foots. </p>
        <p>Can sink nom compewter ur ded how herrow cat. </p>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primarily because `html` is the `:first-child`, so it's essentially the same as saying `html { color: blue; }`, and because CSS *cascades*, other elements inherit it, too. So it essentially applies it to all elements on your page that don't have another color specified because the color is first set on `html`. For example, if you added an `a` tag that **was not** the first child of a parent, that wouldn't inherit this color because a link has it's own color and would overwrite the color on `html`. Here's an example https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/WObbbb

But beyond the style on `html`, every single "first child" of any parent element in your document will be targeted just using `:first-child`, so a lot of your elements are getting `color: blue` applied directly as well as indirectly from inheriting the color from parent elements that are first children.

It's also worth noting this is based on the fact that `color` is an inheritable property in CSS, meaning if you set `color` on a parent element, the color will be inherited to children elements that do not have an explicit color set in CSS or one that is applied via the agent/browser stylesheet. An example of a non-inheritable property is `border` - if there is a border on a parent element, the children will not inherit the border property. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OgPPNK

Comment: Good answer, but I would use a non-inherit property `border` etc as the example, as `<a>` tag is really special in html, like why the color is blue, and it doesn't inherit the color by default, it brings up another question.

Comment: Curiously CSS 2.x and Selectors level 3 define `:first-child` as "The :first-child pseudo-class represents an element that is the first child of *some other element*." which would exclude the `html` element as it is not the child of any other element. Only the Selectors level 4 definition would include the `html` element.

Comment: @Pangloss thanks for the feedback. My point with the `a` is just to illustrate the inheritance - and how if another element had a color either set explicitly or by the browser (in the case of `a`), it wouldn't inherit unless that element was also a "first child." It wasn't about inheritable/non-inheritable CSS properties, like color vs `border` or `background` or something, but that's a good example, too. I'll add that. What do you mean it brings up another question?

Comment: @MichaelCoker A question about the color and inheritance of `<a>` tag, it's already answered - https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144931/483779

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not supply an element, id, or class name before your pseudo class `:first-child`, the application is global. *Every* first child. Therefore, everything.

You can really notice how this works by using an `:nth-child()` selector:

```css
:nth-child(4) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a H6</h1>
    <p>Carz wtf noice pour uh saiz hoi.</p>
    <p>Oh winz lol wuv donutz yu. Herrow not wut carz pwety oh hornz. </p>
    <p>Bere noze dum cheezeburger oh. Notise hai mikrosoft foots. Dum oh iz nuthing gravy haz nozbody finking. Funnae hai nom winz noze r. </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>This is an H1</h1>
    <p>Sheeze dum can compewters flowerz. Loike choosday noice nom samez do hornz mac n. Funnae pour hoi dided gravy samez ghoast I.</p>
    <p> U pwety oh haz cat ghoast hai. Taytoes hornz hunnae hai meeeow ghoast.
    </p>

    <h2>This is an h2</h2>
    <p>Sheeze meeeow dum uh dided cat nom hornz wuv. </p>
    <p>Donutz scratchin mac n dum rong ded gravy.</p>
    <p>Thx chz can hoi wtf. Evrybody yu u ded choosday evrybody hai neether. Iz hai dided sheeze bukket noice nozzing chz watzzup?. </p>
    <h2>this is another h2</h2>
    <p>Graet samez iz iz nozbody saiz sheeze oh carz. Jest kitteh not scratchin herrow. Nom scratchin rong saiz ya kitteh haz chz nom. </p>
    <p>Graet gravy gravy mikrosoft. Dided winz cheezeburger finking samez wtf foots. Gravy wut mac n partay noice noze foots. </p>
    <p>Can sink nom compewter ur ded how herrow cat. </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```