# Why doesn't the anchor tag inherit the color of its parent?

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
  <a href="#">content</a>
</div>
```

```
div {color:red}
```

Why doesn't it inherit the color of the parent and accept the default?

The color of the `content` is blue, not red

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-an-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag check this out

Comment: So that people know it is a link and that they can click on it!!

Comment: @CedricGourville I have seen it. it's correct?

Comment: Anchor elements have a default styling with a color that is specified by the user agent. You will need to override it to change the color. See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Comment: Yeah you have your answer

Comment: @MarkBaijens I know how to apply. Does that mean that user agent style  takes precedence over inheritance? Or is the anchor tag not inheriting?

Comment: @withme user agent style win the game ... in general, inherit is only the last resot if nothing is applied

Answer (score 2):

```
a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

You need to tell it to inherit it.