# How to change color on every element in div when hovering?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to change the color of content, including h4 title, when hovering over div but the title does not get white colored. Don't know how I can achieve this:

```css
.iconbox-blue {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.iconbox-blue:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconbox-blue">
  <a href=''>
    <h4 class="icon-box-title">Header</h4>
  </a>
  <p class="icon-box-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the h4 title color white when hovering over `iconbox-blue` div?

Comment: because the title is in a link, you need to style that separately - links get their own style that need overriding

Comment: links does not inherit color property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-an-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag

Comment: and btw. clean the html. Insert the link inside the `h4` not the header inside the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to simply add a hover effect that changes the anchor-element.
As anchor tag does not inherit attributes like if an href attribute is present.

```
.iconbox-blue:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```css
.iconbox-blue {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.iconbox-blue:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}
.iconbox-blue:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconbox-blue">
  <a href=''>
    <h4 class="icon-box-title">Header</h4>
  </a>
  <p class="icon-box-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Add one additional style for the `H4`:

```
.iconbox-blue:hover,
.iconbox-blue:hover h4 {
   color: #fff;
   background: blue;
}
```