# Setting color of parent element changes color of all text except links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m using this code to change the text color of all of the text on my webpage when hovering over a specific element (a table):

```js
document.getElementById("one").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
document.getElementById("one").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("all").style.color = "white";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("all").style.color = "black";
}
```

All of the text on the page that I want to change color is in a `<div>` with the ID `"all"` and this script works completely fine to change the color of all of the text *except* for the text that is inside of a link (`<a href="url.com">this text will not change color!</a>`).

I’ve tried adding the `"all"` ID to the link but that is not working either. Is there any way to get the links to change color?

Comment: _“I've tried adding the `"all"` ID to the link but that is not working either”_ — IDs must be unique in a document; as a consequence `document.getElementById` will only find the first element matching the given ID. Of course that won’t work. Anyway, see [When will an `<a>` tag not inherit color attribute of parent tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144931/4642212).

Comment: Provide common class to each element. Id can't be duplicate. In case of Id it will select the 1st matching element only. After providing common class to all, use document.getElementsByClassName("yourClassName").style.color = "white";

Comment: @Shubhranshu getElementByClassName returns a set of elements that have that class, so you can't just do an assignment of style. See [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

The a elements are styled by the system unless you override it.

One way of doing this is to change the actions on mouseover/out to add/remove a class to the all element to make the text white. You can then also select the a element.

Here's a snippet:

```html
<style>
#all.mouseover, #all.mouseover a {
  color: white;
}
</style>
<div id="one">Mouseover me</div>
<div id="all">
  Text here
  <a href="#">and this is a link </a>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("one").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
document.getElementById("one").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("all").classList.add('mouseover');
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("all").classList.remove('mouseover');
}
</script>
```

I wasn't sure whether you wanted the a element text to be black or to stay as the default system blue when the mouse isn't over. If you want it black then put `#all a {color: black;}` in the CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much! I also figured out adding style="color: inherit;" like this <a href="url" style="color:inherit;"> linked text </a> worked as well!